# Gmail Contextual Gadget fails in long Conversation Mode Messages

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, gmail-api, gmail-contextual-gadgets

We have been noticing that the Google Gadget is failing in long conversations.

In some cases the gadget will not appear at all in a longer conversation.  In other cases only some of the extractors are available but the gadget is visible.

Note:- this is only happening in long conversations.

I was hoping that others might be able to confirm/deny this behaviour.

To do so - simply open a long Gmail conversation and confirm whether your gadget is working as expected.

Thanks for your help on this!

---

Edit 18/10

I've done some more digging on this issue.  If I debug the gadget the matches Array only has the first two values where as our spec defines 6.

We get matches[2]

matches[0] = date_sent

matches[1] = date_received

So for some reason the matches Array populated by Google is not complete.  On the shorter conversations all 6 matches values are populated....

We get matches[6]

matches[0] = date_sent

matches[1] = date_received

matches[2] = message_id

matches[3] = recipient_to_email

matches[4] = subject

matches[5] = sender_email

Comment: Do you have a sample gadget spec you can provide that exhibits this problem?

Comment: Hi Eric - I have emailed you the details.

Comment: How big does a thread have to be to have this behavior? I loaded a simple Hello World gadget on a thread with 60 messages and didn't get any errors.

Comment: There are other factors here I think.  I for example have 3 gadgets active.  It also seems that if there is some activity occuring in the "init()" of the gadget that this has a bearing.  maybe you could try adding a sleep or loop or something in your Hello World example.  Why don't you add a few other gadgets that fire on init and try your long thread.  You can also experiment with the ?nogadgetcache=1 setting to slow things down a bit more.